# TypeError: No overload matches the getQueriesData function in Next.js 13

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-query

I'm encountering a TypeScript error while using the getQueriesData function in Next.js 13 with React Query. Here's my code:

```
// app/products.tsx

import { getQueryClient } from "@/app/providers/getQueryClient";
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import React from "react";

export interface ProductResponse {
  // Interface definition...
}

// Function definition...

export const ProductList = () => {
  const queryClient = getQueryClient();
  const { data, isLoading, isFetching, error } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["hydrate-users"],
    queryFn: () => getProducts(),
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {
          queryClient.getQueriesData("hydrate-users");
      }}>Revalidate</button>
      {/* Rest of the code */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

My queryClient.tsx:

```
// app/getQueryClient.jsx
import { QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { cache } from "react";

const getQueryClient = cache(() => new QueryClient());
export default getQueryClient;
```

I'm trying to call the getQueriesData function on the queryClient instance, but I'm getting the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(queryKey: QueryKey): [QueryKey, unknown][]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryKey'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(filters: QueryFilters): [QueryKey, unknown][]', gave the following error.
    Type '"hydrate-users"' has no properties in common with type 'QueryFilters'.
```

Comment: Please check API documentation before asking Stackoverflow. [`getQueriesData`](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientgetqueriesdata) does not accept a string as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

*"@tanstack/react-query": "^4.29.12"*

Let's see the TS overload signature and implementation signature of the `getQueriesData()` method:

```
getQueriesData<TQueryFnData = unknown>(
  queryKey: QueryKey,
): [QueryKey, TQueryFnData | undefined][]
getQueriesData<TQueryFnData = unknown>(
  filters: QueryFilters,
): [QueryKey, TQueryFnData | undefined][]
getQueriesData<TQueryFnData = unknown>(
  queryKeyOrFilters: QueryKey | QueryFilters,
): [QueryKey, TQueryFnData | undefined][] {
  return this.getQueryCache()
    .findAll(queryKeyOrFilters)
    .map(({ queryKey, state }) => {
      const data = state.data as TQueryFnData | undefined
      return [queryKey, data]
    })
}
```

And the `QueryKey` type, as you can see, the `queryKey` is a readonly array.

```
export type QueryKey = readonly unknown[]
```

`react-query` check the `queryKey` argument use [`isQueryKey`](https://github.com/TanStack/query/blob/v4.29.12/packages/query-core/src/utils.ts#L395) function, the implementation:

```
export function isQueryKey(value: unknown): value is QueryKey {
  return Array.isArray(value)
}
```

You can match the first overload signature by passing an array of `queryKey`

```
import { QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();
queryClient.getQueriesData(['hydrate-users'])
```